# Magento 2: How to load admin login on home page?

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, cms-pages

I want to display admin login on home page. How can I do this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides from how it is possible, you really don't want to do this. Most people take effort in changing the admin URL into something that cannot be guessed (easily).

There are many automatic crawlers (built by hackers) that crawl the internet in search of Magento webshops. Once they find one, these scripts will test the Magento webshop for vulnerabilities, much like a tool like [MageReport](https://www.magereport.com/) can scan your webshop from the outside also.

One of those vulnerabilities (or at least access to more vulnerabilities) is an "exposed" admin login. Theses scripts will try `/admin/` as very first of course.

When hackers have your admin login URL, then they can try to login your admin by a brute force attack (try many, many user/password combinations, one after another). I've seen such attacks in log files, targeting `/admin/`.

If you have changed your `/admin/` URL, then hackers have to try harder to be able to do such a brute force attack: `/admin/` will return a 404 response.

Now, **if you are giving your admin login away, right on your home page, then you will "set the gates open" to hackers**. So, no, please don't do it! (for whatever the reason might be)

Comment: Thanks for such information I will not go with this way. Really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "admin"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"
```

On your `VirtualHost`, it will force admin context.

Comment: I have tried this this is not working.